# How can I add pods for testing without "repeating" them in my `Podfile` when using multiple Frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

We have multiple Frameworks in our project where a couple are "dependent" of another. For example, `Core` is dependent of `Services`. Almost every Framework has `Pods`.

I want to know how can I "import" each and every pod without needing to add it manually to my target

```
target 'Core' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  project 'Core/Core'
  
  target 'CoreTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths //tried with this but didn't work 

    // I don't want these pods here! because I already imported them in the other Target! 
    pod "Connectivity", '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'MMKV'
    // more pods
  end

end
```

Because if I don't add them there I get this error

```
  Assertions: System: Failed to load the test bundle. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the result bundle at .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-gypebdxyswftyiatctuxslmrqekt/Logs/Test/Test-Core-2021.03.10_14-01-05--0700.xcresult. (Underlying Error: The bundle “CoreTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle. dlopen_preflight(.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-gypebdxyswftyiatctuxslmrqekt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreTests.xctest/CoreTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/Connectivity.framework/Connectivity
  Referenced from: .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-gypebdxyswftyiatctuxslmrqekt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Services.framework/Services
  Reason: image not found)
```

Connectivity is already in `Services` and importing it directly inside my file doesn't seem to work.

How can I add those pods for testing without "repeating" them in my `Podfile`?

Answer (score 2):

The pods you are installing should come prebuilt with the libraries required and not require you to install other pods as part of it such as Firebase coming installed with Google Admob as well to provide support for ad related functions and does not require you to pod install Google Admob even though they also have their own separate pod file. If this is the case, I suggest you look to an alternate solution for this pod

Comment: I think I'm not explaining myself, I have `pod Connectivity` installed in my `Services` target. I import `Services` inside `Core`, so Connectivity should be installed, but it doesn't seem to be